# How to access TabsRouter from child route in Flutter - AutoRoute

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I am trying to get TabsRouter from its child route but it return null (so I guess it cant find any related router in context). Tried a few things read documentation several times. Its either not working as it should or I don't understand.

- Project is only Android and IOS, other platforms not supported.
- Used package: [auto_route](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route)

```dart
AutoRoute(
      path: NavRoutes.authPage,
      page: AuthPage,
      children: [
        AutoRoute(
          path: NavRoutes.loginPage,
          page: LoginPage,
        ),
        AutoRoute(
          path: NavRoutes.signupPage,
          page: SignUpPage,
        ),
      ],
    )

class AuthView extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final cubit = BlocProvider.of<AuthCubit>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: AutoTabsRouter(
          routes: [
            const LoginPageRoute(),
            SignUpPageRoute(
              key: UniqueKey(),
              onGooglePressed: cubit.signInGoogle,
            ),
          ],
          builder: (context, child, animation) {
            return FadeTransition(
              opacity: animation,
              child: child,
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Here I create `AutoTabsRouter` inside AuthView, and try to get it inside any of its child like:

context.innerRouterOf<TabsRouter>(AuthPageRoute.name)?.setActiveIndex(1);
context.innerRouterOf<TabsRouter>(LoginPageRoute.name)?.setActiveIndex(1);
AutoTabsRouter.of(context).setActiveIndex(1);


//tried a few more using innerNavKeys but it also failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try navigating to the target tab ?

```js
context.navigateTo(TargetTabRoute());
```